# Reference for Differences Between Versions of Magento

Tags: magento-1

As I understand it , there was a big change between Magento 1.3 and 1.4 - then the next big change was at 2 ( with maybe some sort of change in version 1.6 )

The problem I have is translating data from an old version of Magento to a new one. I want to know where to find the differences in attribute model ( or some idea as to where I would start looking ) . I'm a bit stumped on how to start with this , the documentation is very thin - and I've purchased a couple of extensions that supposedly do this , but the code / service is absolutely terrible.

So - my specific issue is that I need to map old data to new - and I can't find a good document or reference to show me the differences. specifically around Magento 1 for now.

Comment: You  still using Magento CE 1.3?That is trebill.

Comment: The best approach to upgrade your version to latest version of magento, by upgrading magento version by version, it will take some time but in this case you will let magento do everything for you. but also this way need you to insure that your custom extensions is compatible with the new version, the last time i did that I upgraded magento from 1.4 ->1.9 and it worked for me